# How can I pass a variable into a IIFE?

Tags: javascript

I want to use a closure in `myObj` so I can increment `myIndex` without having to add `myIndex` to the global namespace (aka, in `TaskHandler`).

That works. But I also need to pass in `myValue` to the closure. I thought passing it through `(function (param) { })(myValue);` was the way to do it. But it's undefined.

```
TaskHandler.myFunction(value);

TaskHandler = {

     myFunction : function (value) {
         this.myObj.run(value);
     },

    myObj : {

        run : function (value) {
            this.doIt(value);
        },

        doIt : (function (value) {
            var myIndex = 0;
             return function () {
                myIndex++;
                 doSomethingWithValue(myIndex, value); //value undefined
             }
        })(value)

    },
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function your IIFE returns should accept the value argument, not the IIFE itself:

```
    doIt : (function () {
        var myIndex = 0;
         return function (value) {
            myIndex++;
             doSomethingWithValue(myIndex, value);
         }
    })()
```

Comment: When is it that you pass the param through the IIFE then?

Comment: @Growler , when you have the value you want to pass in at the time the IIFE is executed. You don't have the value you want to pass in at that point (when the objectia being created), you have it later, when run is called, and at that point `this.doit` is a reference to the inner anonymous function. `this.doit` is never a reference to the IIFE, since it executes immediately and returns the inner function.